# how can I change buttons's text in org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard

Tags: java, internationalization, swt, jface, wizard

I want to change text of button in `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard` to arabic in button bar?
I mean I wanna change label "Next" button to "بعدی".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of the `Wizard`'s labels is handled by JFace and uses your OS's region settings. That means if you're machine is set to "English (UK)" you will see the labels in English, if it's set to "Germany" you'll see them in German, etc.

There are related questions here:

- [JFace dialog button translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854066/jface-dialog-button-translation)
- [How to set custom text on buttons in JFace Wizard (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289553/how-to-set-custom-text-on-buttons-in-jface-wizard-java)

---

**Update**:

If you're using a `WizardDialog` you can override the method [`createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/WizardDialog.html#createButtonsForButtonBar(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite)) like it's done [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html).